# How does one work with Telerik dropdowns in Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, telerik, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have just started using Selenium Webdriver.
But am stuck with Telerik drop downs.

I cannot use SelectElement, because the dropdown appears in a span element.
How do I read all available options in the dropdown and then make the selection.

Adding more information:
The dropdown is populated by JSON/JQuery. The HTML sample is below. The text between the span elements changes depending on what you have selected from the dropdown. All options from the dropdown are not available anywhere in the generated HTML.

```
<div class="t-dropdown-wrap t-state-default">
<span class="t-input">To be approved</span>
```

My guess is I have to execute javascript. Unsure how to go about it.

Comment: We'd need to see an example of what this looks like (in terms of what HTML markup is produced) to have much of a chance of helping you.

Comment: Put html around the select so that we can help you

Comment: Responding to more information:  "The dropdown is populated by JSON/JQuery" -- does this happen when you click on the drop-down arrow?  If so, then my answer should still work, because after you use the WebDriver to click the dropdown, the list is populated, which means its contents were added to the HTML, which allows the WebDriver to select an option.  Thus, no need to directly execute JavaScript with Selenium.

Answer (score 4):

Your question has two parts:

1. **Generally:** Selecting WebElements within other WebElements
2. **Specifically:** Reading all options in the dropdown and selecting one of them

While answering, I will assume you have a WebDriver object named "Driver".

#### Selecting WebElements within other WebElements

First off, I'm not sure why you mentioned `SelectElement` -- I believe the method you want is `FindElement()`.
You can call `FindElement()` off of any SearchContext.  A WebDriver object is a SearchContext, so you can (theoretically) find a WebElement anywhere on the page by calling `Driver.FindElement()`.
A WebElement itself is **also** a SearchContext, so you can also call `.FindElement()` off of a WebElement that you've already found.  This is useful for narrowing the search down from the entire page to within a specific element.

#### Reading All Options in the Dropdown and Selecting One of Them

I looked up an example of a Telerik Dropdown to see what you might be dealing with.  I found one **[here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/dropdownlist/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx).**

First, you need to open the drop down by clicking on the down arrow icon.  It seems that the icon is coded like this:

```
<span class="rddlIcon"></span>
```

If there's only one of these on the page, you can find it and click it like this:

```
Driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("rddlIcon")).Click();
```

It seems that the Dropdown code looks like this:

```
<ul class="rddlList">
   <li class="rddlItem">Item One</li>
   <li class="rddlItem">Item Two</li>
   <li class="rddlItem">Item Three</li>
</ul>
```

What you want to do here is select the <ul> WebElement, and then from there find the list item you want.

```
WebElement List = Driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("rddlList"));
//Get Item Three
WebElement Item = List.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[text()='Item Three']");
Item.click();
```